# Is there something wrong with my sql or php? (CAN'T LOGIN)

Tags: php, sql, authentication

I can't get any result from a function `attempt_login()` that I made myself. Can anyone figure out any errors or what is wrong with this piece of code? It worked for only one user that I created in the database. I want to get a boolean in return and afterwards wanna check if the result is true, than store it into the session and then redirect the user to a specific page. Please help!
CODE:

```
function attempt_login($theusername, $thepassword){
    $host = 'localhost';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $database = 'website';
    $con = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database);

    $theusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $theusername);
    $thepassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $thepassword);
    $thepassword = md5($thepassword);

    $query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '{$theusername}' AND password = '{$thepassword}'";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    return isset($row['name']);

    mysqli_close($con); 
}
```

SCREEN SHOT:  [image]

Comment: md5 is not a good way to encrypt passwords. If you have PHP 5.5 look at the `password_hash` function.

Comment: Quick note, `mysqli_close($con);` will never be reached because there is an unconditional `return` before it.

Comment: `var_dump($row)` and see what that gives you.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Well ok but this doesn't seems to be an error does it?

Comment: Is there column 'name'  in table `members`?

Comment: are you getting anything at all? Does the function return at all? What errors you're getting?

Comment: Im not getting anything at all

Comment: I is working with only one record

Comment: let me add a screen shot of database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say your password is `abc'123` - you know, a good mix of letters, numbers and symbols.

`mysqli_real_escape_string` will transform that into `abc\'123`.

`md5` then makes it `af94b3b7388e50429710ed345b58c01c`

But in the database, the password `abc'123` should be encrypted as `bb7e1fc94ff2a3e8d2d79c8ab055da60`, which is significantly different!

Try moving the `md5` call *before* the `mysqli_real_escape_string`.

---

EDIT: Your first user works because the password is fishman001

The second, however, is the empty string. You are probably using `if( empty($_POST['password']))` or similar to see if a password was submitted. The empty string will fail this test.

PS: Rainbow tables. Love 'em. Now stop using MD5.

Comment: This is STILL important to do though, or you WILL get problems if anyone uses a ' in their password.

Comment: actually i always use a password as a second argument

Comment: But the string is not empty

Comment: Just change that user's password to something that isn't "nothing". Then stop using MD5, or at the very least salt your hashes.

Comment: I was using my another function `sign_up()` and I was using `$password` two times, one for the signing up and second for the database password. Well thanks!